# create an ios progress bar without rounded corners

Tags: ios

I'm looking to remove the corner radius on the iOS progress bar component. The standard methods don't seem to work. Is there a straight forward way to get a squared progress bar in iOS 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customize the progress bar (using the proper `UIProgressBar` APIs) by providing your own `progressImage` and `trackImage` images without rounded corners.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that was the way to go. I tried adding images in the drop downs for the progress bar component but no avail. Is this something that should be done in code?